# Instance of a class in Create method of JobBuilder in quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

The default create method of JobBuilder is

```
IJobDetail paymentJob = JobBuilder.Create<Hello>().WithIdentity(jobName, groupName).Build();
```

I checked the overloads but there is no overload in which we can have an instance of a class inside. the create method. Something like this

```
IJobDetail paymentJob = JobBuilder.Create<new Hello()>().WithIdentity(jobName, groupName).Build();
```

but this gives an error

> Operator < cannot be applied to the 'method group' or 'Hello'

The reason i need this is:

```
public abstract class Hello:IJob
{
    public abstract void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context);
}

public Hello1: Hello
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}

public Hello2: Hello
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
public static HelloFactory
{

    public Hello GetHelloType(HelloEnum enum)
    {
        Hello job = new Hello();
        switch(enum)
        {
            case HelloEnum.Type1: job = new Hello1();
            case HelloEnum.Type2: job = new Hello2();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The scheduler expects you to pass in a job type (class) and it will create an actual instance of the job for you. This is by design... what is your question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i have a factory class so i need the specific instance to be selected.. ill update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your HelloFactory to return a Type object instead of a Hello object:

```
public static class HelloFactory
{

    public Type GetHelloType(HelloEnum theEnum)
    {
        Type type;
        switch (theEnum)
        {
            case HelloEnum.Type1:
                type = typeof(Hello1);
                break;
            case HelloEnum.Type2: job = typeof(Hello2);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Alternatively, implement your own JobFactory. Here's an exmaple on how to implement one:
http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/23/creating-a-custom-quartz-net-jobfactory/

Comment: Oh got it instead of IJob implemented IJobFactory. The link was very helpful thanks..